# How to calculate the number of possible ways in a quiz? Java, JSON

Tags: java, json

So, I'm working on the project that conducts a quiz. I use simple.json library to work with JSON data. In my case, there are such possible questions and answers:

```
{"What is your marital status?": ["Single", "Married"]}
{"Are you planning on getting married next year?": ["Yes", "No"]}
{"How long have you been married?": ["Less than a year", "More than a year"]}
{"Have you celebrated your one year anniversary?": ["Yes", "No"]}
```

Each subsequent question is determined depending on the previous answer.

I've implemented the logic of this determining. I've created the JSON file of the below structure:

```
{
  "What is your marital status?": {
    "Single": "Are you planning on getting married next year?",
    "Married": "How long have you been married?"
  },
  "Are you planning on getting married next year?": {
    "Yes": "0 Thanks for your answers! We hope that you will build a cool family!",
    "No": "0 Thanks for your answers! Who knows, maybe you'll find someone significant in your life!"
  },
  "How long have you been married?": {
    "Less than a year": "0 Thanks for your answers! We hope that you will celebrate your one year anniversary soon!",
    "More than a year": "Have you celebrated your one year anniversary?"
  },
  "Have you celebrated your one year anniversary?": {
    "Yes": "0 Wow, cool! Keep it up! Thanks for your answers.",
    "No": "0 We think you should fix it next time! Thanks for your answers!"
  }
}
```

And wrote the class that handles this quiz:

```
public class QuizHandler {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("QuizHandler");
    public void runQuiz(JSONObject configuration) {
        List<Object> keys = configuration.keySet().stream().toList();
        LOGGER.info("keys: " + keys);
        String question = "What is your marital status?";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (question.charAt(0) != '0') {
            System.out.println(question);
            System.out.println("Possible answers: " + ((JSONObject) configuration.get(question)).keySet().toString());
            question = ((JSONObject) configuration.get(question)).get(scanner.nextLine()).toString();
        }
        System.out.println(question.substring(2));
    }
}
```

0s at the beginning of some answers mean that this is the end of the quiz.

Everything works fine.

***But, then I have to determine the number of possible ways to go over this quiz and send something like this as an answer:***

```
{paths: {number: 3, list: [
   [{"What is your marital status?": "Single"},
   {"Are you planning on getting married next year?": "Yes/No"}],
   [{"What is your marital status?": "Married"},
   {"How long have you been married?": "Less than a year"}],
   [{"What is your marital status?": "Married"},
   {"How long have you been married?": "More than a year"},
   {"Have you celebrated your one year anniversary?": "Yes/No"}],
]}}
```

I've created a class for this purpose:

```
public class QuizService {
    // TODO: Implement a method that will count the number of possible ways to go through the quiz
}
```

**How can I implement this?
And, did I choose the right approach designing the logic of the quiz?**

Comment: Your initial approach of having `"Question": {"Answer1": ..., "Answer2": ...}` was a good idea imo, you just didn't quite take it far enough. You can keep going with the follow-up questions and provide another level of object/keys that they can reply with (or an array of possible answers to move on). To create an "answer", you can simply set hard values instead of objects/arrays: `{"Marital Status": {"Single": {"Next Year": "Yes"}}}`.

Comment: Thanks, @Rogue, it does make sense. Will try to go this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion

```
private static int countWays(JsonNode node, String question) {
    JsonNode answers = node.get(question);
    if (answers == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    AtomicInteger ways = new AtomicInteger();
    answers.fields().forEachRemaining(answer ->
        ways.addAndGet(countWays(node, answer.getValue().asText())));
    return ways.get();
}
```

Let's go

```
JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(
    "{" +
    "  \"What is your marital status?\": {" +
    "    \"Single\": \"Are you planning on getting married next year?\"," +
    "    \"Married\": \"How long have you been married?\"" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"Are you planning on getting married next year?\": {" +
    "    \"Yes\": \"0 Thanks for your answers! We hope that you will build a cool family!\"," +
    "    \"No\": \"0 Thanks for your answers! Who knows, maybe you'll find someone significant in your life!\"" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"How long have you been married?\": {" +
    "    \"Less than a year\": \"0 Thanks for your answers! We hope that you will celebrate your one year anniversary soon!\"," +
    "    \"More than a year\": \"Have you celebrated your one year anniversary?\"" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"Have you celebrated your one year anniversary?\": {" +
    "    \"Yes\": \"0 Wow, cool! Keep it up! Thanks for your answers.\"," +
    "    \"No\": \"0 We think you should fix it next time! Thanks for your answers!\"" +
    "  }" +
    "}");
System.out.println(countWays(node, "What is your marital status?"));
// Output 8
```